# Unable to remove project from Switch Project panel even deleted from sublime_session file

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
Sublime Text 3 build 3143

I have added one project and save the project and it is visible in Switch Project Panel (`^ + ⌘ + p`)

Now I have deleted that project from physical location But it is still visible in Switch Project Panel.

I have search over SO and got [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744365/removing-projects-in-sublime-text-2-and-3) . and deleted the entry from *Session.sublime_session* file located at *~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/* and quit the ST3 and start again but it does not go away.

Is this a bug in ST3 or there need to be doing something more.

There must be some way to clear the project list other than *clear Items* option which causes the loss of all project with their settings.

Comment: Did you edit the session file using Sublime itself? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: No I opened file in text editor

Comment: The only other reason I can see for that not working would be if Sublime was running while you edited the session file. It writes the session when it quits, which contains the information that it already knows about.